# codeigniter pagination not working when there is a query string

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, query-string

i'm using latest version of codeigniter(2.1.4).In admin when i'm sending query string then pagination not working.And i want my url will be like mydomain/commission/user_id/page_no.
ex: mydomain/commission/20/1
 Below is my code

```
$config['per_page'] = 2;
$config['total_rows']=100;
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin_vendor/commissions/'.$this->uri->segment(3);
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;     
$config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['enable_query_strings']=FALSE;
$config['num_links'] = 20;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a>';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';         
$config['next_link'] = 'Next&gt;';      
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';      
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';        
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;Prev';      
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$page = $this->uri->segment(4);         
$limit_end = ($page * $config['per_page']) - $config['per_page'];
if ($limit_end < 0){
 $limit_end = 0;
}
```

please guide me. Thanks

Comment: `$config['enable_query_strings']=TRUE;` its false in your case

Comment: where is `$config['uri_segment']`? and why are you sending query string? send it as a segment?

Comment: $config['enable_query_strings']=TRUE;  when i did this 'next' button not coming.

Comment: here is my remaining code   $data['count_commission']= $this->admin_vendor_model->count_commission($this->uri->segment(3));
            $data['commission'] = $this->admin_vendor_model->get_commission($this->uri->segment(3),$config['per_page'],$limit_end);        
            $config['total_rows'] = $data['count_commission'];
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['main_content'] = 'admin/view_vendor_commission';
            $this->load->view('admin/includes/template', $data);

Comment: It is working perfectly,when there is no query string

Comment: Post the `url` with `query string` which is creating problem.

Comment: Nil'z,please post the answer.how do i send query string in pagination.Though i sending it through  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin_vendor/commissions/'.$this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: I need to know how you are sending the query string in the url first, post the url which is not working with the pagination.

Comment: Your base url is wrong, why are you appending the current page to the base? Remove the .$this->uri->segment(3) and add the config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri_segment(3) to your config You may also have to adjust your route to add /(:any) to the end of it for the query string, not sure. You still haven't posted the problematic URL and the URL's you posted in the OP don't have query strings.

Comment: When using Page numbers, You'll have to calculate the offset yourself so you either use query_string which would use offsets or you use page_numbers where you have to calculate the offset from page number yourself.

Answer (score 0):

go to application/config.php file

and change `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;` to

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

It will work